# EXTJS4 XML Store - XTemplate

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have the following template:

```
myStore.on('load', function(store, records, options) {
        console.log(records);
        alert("loaded.");
        var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<tpl for=".">',
            '<h1>{name} test</h1>',
            '<h1>{origin}</h1>',
            '</tpl>'
        );

        tpl.append(Ext.get("output-body"), myStore);

 });
```

It loops through my store which has 3 records:

```
accounts { id="accounts-ext-record-1", internalId="ext-record-1"}   
name = "Network"    origin = "Support_4"    id = undefined
accounts { id="accounts-ext-record-2", internalId="ext-record-2"}   
name = "new"    origin = "nevil-nmshub" id = undefined
accounts { id="accounts-ext-record-3", internalId="ext-record-3"}   
name = "soap"   origin = "network"  id = undefined
```

When I run the code I get:

```
test
test
test
```

What am I missing to output the values of "name" and "origin"? Something is working as its obvioulsy seeting the 3 accounts hence the 3 prints of "test". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add data. in my tpl.

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<tpl for=".">',
            '<h1>{data.name} test</h1>',
            '<h1>{data.origin}</h1>',
            '</tpl>'
        );
```